# 3 Dimensional Array

Tags: c#

I don't know why I'm experiencing so much trouble with this, but I would like to have an array that basically represents a layer number and x,y coordinates so I could essentially say,

int i = array[layer,x,y] and get the corrisponding value per layer.  I create the array..

```
int[,,] myarray
```

...initialize it

```
 myarray = new int[0,width, height];
```

...and it blows up when try and grab a value.

```
int n = myarray[0,1,1]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing an array with 0 as a length. Use 1:

```
myarray = new int[1,width, height];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myarray = new int[0,width, height];
```

You just told the computer that the length of the first dimension of the array is 0. Basically, your array can hold nothing.

In C#, the value you use in the array declaration indicates the *length* of the dimension. It's different than if you are coming from a language such as Visual Basic, where the value indicates the *upper bound.*

```
Dim array(4) as Integer
```

Array of 5 integer elements in VB

```
int[] array = new int[4];
```

Array of 4 integer elements in C#

Answer (score 1):

Try using a non-zero value for the first array dimension.